# improving a function in python

Tags: function, python-2.7

I created this function to figure out if betting either side of proposition bet on how many 3 pointers there will be in a particular basketball game is profitable.  I project how many total three pointers will be made **pjTotal3s** and the standard deviation **pjGame3STD** earlier in the code.  The **threes_over** is the the number given to me by the betting site for which I try to find if the total number of threes will be over or under that number. In this case it is 14.5.

```
threes_over = 14.5

def overunder(n):
over_count = 0
under_count = 0
push_count = 0
overodds = 0
underodds = 0
for i in range(n):
    if round(np.random.normal(pjTotal3s,pjGame3STD)) > threes_over:
        over_count = over_count + 1
    if round(np.random.normal(pjTotal3s,pjGame3STD)) < threes_over:
        under_count = under_count +1
    if round(np.random.normal(pjTotal3s,pjGame3STD)) == threes_over:
        push_count = push_count + 1
return over_count, under_count, push_count
```

Then I simulate it a 100,000 **overunder(100000)** times and it gives me how many times the number of three pointers will be over, under or equal to the number given.  This works fine but I still have to more work to do to find if it is a profitable bet.

Assuming that this the output (57550, 42646, 0)  I have to manually input it like so and do more to find out if either side of the bet is worthwhile.

```
over_count = 57550
under_count = 42646
over = 1/(over_count / (over_count + under_count))
under = 1/ (under_count / (over_count + under_count))
over_odds_given = 1.77
under_odds_given = 2.05
overedge = 1/over * over_odds_given - 1
underedge = 1/under * under_odds_given - 1
print overedge, underedge
```

How do I combine the second set of calculations into the same function as the first.  I would like to avoid having to manually input the results of the first function in order to save time and avoid inputting a wrong number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want the second bit of code in the same function as the first, you could just paste all but the part where you set the over_count and under_count into the function...

```
def overunder(n):
  over_count = 0
  under_count = 0
  push_count = 0
  overodds = 0
  underodds = 0
  for i in range(n):
    if round(np.random.normal(pjTotal3s,pjGame3STD)) > threes_over:
      over_count = over_count + 1
    if round(np.random.normal(pjTotal3s,pjGame3STD)) < threes_over:
      under_count = under_count +1
    if round(np.random.normal(pjTotal3s,pjGame3STD)) == threes_over:
      push_count = push_count + 1

  over = 1/(over_count / float(over_count + under_count))
  under = 1/ (under_count / float(over_count + under_count))
  over_odds_given = 1.77
  under_odds_given = 2.05
  overedge = 1/over * over_odds_given - 1
  underedge = 1/under * under_odds_given - 1

  print overedge, underedge

  return over_count, under_count, push_count
```

Or, probably better, you could put the second bit of code (overedge, underedge) into a separate function and pass it the results from overunder:

```
def edges(over_count, under_count, push_count):
  over = 1/(over_count / float(over_count + under_count))
  under = 1/ (under_count / float(over_count + under_count))
  over_odds_given = 1.77
  under_odds_given = 2.05
  overedge = 1/over * over_odds_given - 1
  underedge = 1/under * under_odds_given - 1
  print overedge, underedge
```

And then call it with the results from overunder:

```
c = overunder(100000)
edges(c[0],c[1],c[2])
```